# PHP Not detecting class properlly

Tags: php

For some reason it's **not detecting the class files in the specified directory**.
I'm unsure what the problem is here. Could anyone brighten this up for me?

Code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class main
{

  public static
         $test;
}

foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/engine/*.php') as $file) {
  include($file);

}


main::$test = new Test();
 ?>
```

As you can see i'm trying to include all php files from `/engine.php/*`

Project file structure:
http://prntscr.com/hutqyo

But I'm getting the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Test' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\loader.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\loader.php on line 23

Here is my `test.class.php` code there isn't a lot in it yet. As i'm still working on this current problem:

```
<title>test</title>


    <?php

    class Test
    {

      function getIP(){

      }

    }
     ?>
```

Thanks to anyone that could possibly help me find the solution!

Comment: please check the output of `echo $file;` inside the loop whether it is giving the correct path of the file you want to include.

Comment: Have you tried manually including the file? Did that work?

Comment: I strongly suggest you use composers autoloading instead of rolling your own

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hutx9f